# Casting Array of type Object to Array of another type

Tags: arrays, vb.net, casting

I am trying to cast an array of type object to be an array of another. Any idea?

```
Public Sub LogInfo(ByVal logMessage As Object(), ByVal functionName As String)
 ...
Dim listTp() As ThirdParties
' here I want to cast my logMessage to be of type ThirdParties

End Sub
```

I have tried a solution suggested in  MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbatye4h.aspx , but it is not working, an error is returned telling me that ThirdParties is not a reference Type.

Comment: There [Array.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) but it's hard to help you without knowing the definition of ThirdParties is. Your solution might be to just loop all items of the array and convert them one by one.

Comment: Casting a reference type is for when something is Object but you know its really something else.  Casting the `sender As Object` to a button or textbox in an event handler.  It cant create something from nothing or create a cat from a dog